# Is there a convention for Win32 message parameters use?

Tags: pointers, winapi, memory-management, message-queue

I read that each message has its own way of using lparam and wparam. I couldn't find any convention about when we pass pointers, who is responsible for memory handling. Should the caller keep track or the message handler should take care of it? I sense that in messaging model it would be hard for caller to manage the memory. Because it won't know when the resource is no longer needed for the message handler. On the other hand that is known as a bad practice in C++ programming. Would you please help me on this?

Comment: It depends. If the message is delivered asynchronously, then the caller has to take on responsibility. Otherwise, there is a choice to be made. No one size fits all solution. You need to define the usage before you can decide.

Comment: If you are trying to solve a specific problem, do let us know, what problem that is. If you are just curious, then [What do the letters W and L stand for in WPARAM and LPARAM?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031125-00/?p=41713) might be for you.

Comment: I am thinking about the design of my application. I want to choose the correct way to implement messaging.

Comment: It's *your* application. You can make the rules. If you want to transfer ownership/responsibility of resources, then there's nothing stopping you.

Comment: If you need pointers, then lParam is usually the one because it used to be of "long" type. You can use WM_GETTEXT or WM_GETMINMAXINFO  as example when callee must write into lParam (provided by caller) and WM_NOTIFY when callee reads from caller (and does not deallocate). In general, details are added for specifics, for ex: WM_COPYDATA. This is for SendMessage calls. For PostMessage calls this is another story. Some APIS handle all that in an opaque way with wrapper methods: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/sendmessage--postmessage--and-related-functions and warn you.

Answer (score 0):

I conclude it is completely by code designer on how message parameters are managed. I also note that if a message is posted aysnc either the resource should be freed by message handler or somehow sender must be signaled by message handler that the resource passed in lparam or wparam is no longer needed.